# Storing data in MySql using a procedure where the number of relations to add is unknown

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a basic database in MySql where I store a movie along with the movie_genre and movie_country. When storing to the database I use C# I do something like:

```
Create Connection;
Open Connection;
Insert Movie(mTitle, mYear);
MovieID = LastInsertedID;
ForEach s in ListofGenres
    Insert Movie_Genre(MovieID, s);
Close Connection;
```

In C# its easy to iterate through a list and just store the said number. Now I'm trying to create a stored procedure which will accept the data and then process it accordingly. The problem is how can I pass in something like:

```
//C#
CALL insertMovie(mTitle(string), mYear(string), mGenre(Array? List? concatString?))

//MySQL
Procedure insertMovie(mTitle varchar, mYear varchar, mGenre(Array? List? concatString?))
   Insert into movie(mTite, mYear);
   Declare id int;
   Select last_inserted_id() into id;  //No idea beyond this point
   Loop
       Insert into movie_genre(id, mGenre[i]);
```

Is there some way to pass in some sort of array of the data? If it must be a string then how can I retrieve the said number of entries from the string and store each one in their relation? Is there some way to retrieve each relation string from inside the concatenated string? Or is it best to just keep the system which I currently have? Which is slow when you add in a bunch of actors and directors and so on.

Comment: To put it simply, one cannot.  Workarounds for passing collections of data to a stored procedure include: prepopulating a `TEMPORARY TABLE` which is read by the procedure; and serialising the data into a string argument which is then deserialised within the procedure.  However, neither are ideal.  The "real" answer is that this is not what sprocs are for: to insert bulk data, you might instead find it easier to prepare a statement which is then repeatedly executed within a loop with different parameter values.